# How to download from a data source extension into excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, domo

I have an online data source that I've linked to excel using the domo excel extension. This enables me to download data tables straight from domo into a an excel doc. My goal is to use a macro to automate the following steps:

1. At a 12am ET on Sunday morning, open an new excel document
2. Access the extension and download a data table
3. Save the newly populated excel table as "Data File (date)" into a specific folder.

In my limited experience with VBA, i attempted to record even just the download process from an open sheet and excel stops recording as soon as I click on the extension tab.

two-part question: First, is there a way to access the extension via my macro? If so, is it possible to schedule the desired process?

Thank you!

Comment: Answer to your 2nd part is yes. There are several ways: Windows Task Scheduler is one. First part is hard to answer. Does Domo provide an API that Excel can talk to?

Comment: Not sure about an API. I've just got their basic excel extension which only enables me to select and download any of the data tables into a spreadsheet. Not much functionality in the extension. It's like the bounds of VBA don't recognize 3rd party extensions (or at least this 3rd party extension)

Comment: look at Tools>References in the VBA and see if there is any resource related to domo. If so, check it and then you can use it. maybe there's some help online for it as well.